# Prove that if $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n \geq 3$ then $n! + 3$ is composite.

Tags: proof-verification, factorial

Prove that if $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n \geq 3$ then $n! + 3$ is composite.

I tried factoring it to show that there are two factors, thus composites but I can't figure out how to get rid of the constant in the equation. Any suggestions for how I could approach this?

Comment: $3|n!$, so $n!=3k, k\ge 1$ and $n!+3=3(k+1)$ is a factorization.

Comment: Sorry, how do we know that 3 | n!?

Comment: definition of divisibility is that $a|b\iff \exists m\in\Bbb Z$ such that $b=am$. Then $n!=n(n-1)\ldots (4)(2)(1)\cdot 3$ so clearly there is such a $k$.

Comment: **Hint** $\,\ 3\mid m\,\Rightarrow\, 3\mid m\!+\!3.\,$ Yours is special case $\,m = n!,\ n\ge 3.\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Prove that $3$ divides $n!+3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$n!=1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots n$$

$$n!+3=1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots n+3=3(1 \cdot 2 \cdot 4 \cdots n+1)$$

We see that $3 \mid n!+3 \Rightarrow n!+3=3k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$

$n \geq 3 \Rightarrow n! \geq 6 \Rightarrow n!+3 \geq 9, \text{ that implies that } k \geq 3.$

So, $n!+3$ is composite.

Answer (score 0):

If $3\leq n$ then $n! = 1·2·3·\ldots ·n = 3(1·2·4·\ldots ·n)$ so $n! + 3 = 3(1·2·4·\ldots ·n) + 3 = 3(1+1·2·4·\ldots ·n)$ so $n!+3$ is divisible by $3$.